# sql if incorrect syntax

Tags: sql, if-statement, syntax

the sql statement below (without the if) returns 1 row, 1 column = 8. but with the if i get a syntax error on SELECT and on <. what im trying to do is if there are less than 50 rows returned test true. false if 50 rows are returned.

thanks for the help

```
IF SELECT COUNT([VDeck_ID]) FROM [SecondLifeDatabases].[dbo].[YuGiOh-Cards]
    WHERE [User_ID] = 
            (SELECT [ID] FROM [SecondLifeDatabases].[dbo].[YuGiOh-Users] 
            WHERE [UUID] = 'D38C3475-C995-4EB2-85D0-F2A3ED1D23A0') 
                and [VDeck_ID] = 
                    (SELECT [ID] FROM [SecondLifeDatabases].[dbo].[YuGiOh-VDecks]
                        WHERE [DeckName] = 'NewDeckName')
    < 50
BEGIN
    UPDATE [SecondLifeDatabases].[dbo].[YuGiOh-Cards] 
    SET [VDeck_ID] = 
        (SELECT [ID] FROM [SecondLifeDatabases].[dbo].[YuGiOh-VDecks] 
        WHERE [User_ID] = 
            (SELECT [ID] FROM [SecondLifeDatabases].[dbo].[YuGiOh-Users] 
            WHERE [UUID] = 'D38C3475-C995-4EB2-85D0-F2A3ED1D23A0') 
                and [DeckName] = 'NewDeckName') 
                WHERE [ID] = '11'
END
```

Comment: Which SQL? MySQL or MS SQL or Oracle? I guess MS SQL...

Comment: @PraveenKumar: "[dbo]" is usually a field mark of Microsoft SQL Server.

Comment: @Catcall That's the reason I said it might be MS SQL.

Answer (score 2):

Put parentheses around the `select` statement in the `if` clause:

```
IF (SELECT COUNT([VDeck_ID]) FROM [SecondLifeDatabases].[dbo].[YuGiOh-Cards]
    WHERE [User_ID] = 
            (SELECT [ID] FROM [SecondLifeDatabases].[dbo].[YuGiOh-Users] 
            WHERE [UUID] = 'D38C3475-C995-4EB2-85D0-F2A3ED1D23A0') 
                and [VDeck_ID] = 
                    (SELECT [ID] FROM [SecondLifeDatabases].[dbo].[YuGiOh-VDecks]
                        WHERE [DeckName] = 'NewDeckName')
   )
    < 50
BEGIN
    UPDATE [SecondLifeDatabases].[dbo].[YuGiOh-Cards] 
    SET [VDeck_ID] = 
        (SELECT [ID] FROM [SecondLifeDatabases].[dbo].[YuGiOh-VDecks] 
        WHERE [User_ID] = 
            (SELECT [ID] FROM [SecondLifeDatabases].[dbo].[YuGiOh-Users] 
            WHERE [UUID] = 'D38C3475-C995-4EB2-85D0-F2A3ED1D23A0') 
                and [DeckName] = 'NewDeckName') 
                WHERE [ID] = '11'
END
```

Answer (score 0):

You need brackets...

```
IF (SELECT COUNT(..) FROM ...) > 50
```